Javascript error when browse SharePoint libraries within Office clients
When we open or save files in a SharePoint library from within Word, Excel or other client applications, we get javascript errors in the browse window. There are always two errors, one from init.js and another from core.js. You are asked whether you want to continue running scripts and once the errors have been clicked away, everything works as normal. These errors only occur within the client applications, not when you access the library via the browser.

An error has occurred in the script on this page
Line: 1
Character: 118138
Error: Identifier expected.
Code: 0
URL: https://sharepoint/_layouts/15/init.js
Do you want to continue running scripts on this page? Yes/No

We have SharePoint SE on premise and the latest Office.

Do you have any custom scripts, macros, custom solutions installed?
It's really weird that it's coming from client applications, I would expect it rather from a browser

Do you see anything in the logs?

We have implemented some customizations, but these errors began after this summer, and nothing has changed since then. I can't find anything useful in the logs.

We have the same issue after installing the august 2024 CU. I believe our previous CU was may 2024. It has also been reported here:
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2024/08/15/august-2024-cu-for-sharepoint-server-subscription-edition-is-available-for-download/
